# preloading fonts with Nuxt js

Tags: css, fonts, nuxt.js, preload

I am trying to optimize my page [www.gamestegy.com](http://www.gamestegy.com) and for example on this link https://www.gamestegy.com/read-post/233/alistair-the-juggernaut-build when I check it on PageSpeed Insights, I get this message: Preload key requests. Which would allow me to save almost 2 seconds.

My current setup is that I have a font.css file in assets folder where the fonts are imported in this manner:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono';
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  font-weight: 500;
  src: local('IBM Plex Mono Medium'), local('IBMPlexMono-Medium'),
    url('../fonts/ibm-plex-mono-v5-latin-ext_latin-500.woff2') format('woff2'),
    /* Chrome 26+, Opera 23+, Firefox 39+ */
      url('../fonts/ibm-plex-mono-v5-latin-ext_latin-500.woff') format('woff'); /* Chrome 6+, Firefox 3.6+, IE 9+, Safari 5.1+ */
}
```

The assets folder also contains the woff2 and woff files which are being imported to font.css

Now this setup doesn't have any preloading (from what I understand). So I tried to investigate how to setup preloading and one of the options I found was to use in nuxt.config.js:

```
  render: {
    bundleRenderer: {
      shouldPreload: (file, type) => {
        return ['script', 'style', 'font'].includes(type);
      }
    }
  },
```

However, this imports all of the font files which may not be necessary for the page (in total 20+ imports). How do I do font preloading importing correctly?

Regards,
Rokas

Answer (score 0):

hey i had the same problem and of course it was one of the gtmetrix warnings , so after many searches i found out i can put my code in the layouts/default.vue ( the name of directory can be different in some projects but this is a file that u can define your header and footer components like this:

```
<SiteHeader />

<nuxt /> ( your content )

<SiteFooter />
```

any way in the template of this default.vue that i mentioned u can simply add your code like other sites:

```
<template>
<div>
<link rel="preload" as="style" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" crossorigin="anonymous" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'"/>
</dive>
<SiteHeader />

<nuxt /> ( your content )

<SiteFooter />
</template>
```

hope this be helpful and apologize for my bad english